# Application lock for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've an application that schedules a job. I've limited control on the Job. This job executes a Stored Procedure. Is there any way I can get lock of Stored Procedure so that jobs couldn't execute this stored procedure concurrently?
I want to check if there is something that SQL server offers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) to get a 'custom' or 'application' lock and [sp_releaseapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to release it.

Helper functions are:

- [APPLOCK_TEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/applock-test-transact-sql) - Returns information as to whether or not a lock can be granted on a particular application resource
- [APPLOCK_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/applock-mode-transact-sql) - This function returns the lock mode held by the lock owner on a particular application resource

Please be aware, the `sp_getapplock` will not lock any tables in the database, it will just create a custom named lock. Applications can use this feature to handle concurrency.

**Example:**

Open 2 query windows in SSMS and run the code below in both within 1 minute.

```
DECLARE
        @LockResult         INT
    ,   @LockErrorMessage   NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Failed to acquire lock.'
;

EXEC @LockResult = sys.sp_getapplock
        @Resource       = N'TestResource'
    ,   @LockMode       = N'Exclusive'
    ,   @LockOwner      = N'Session'
    ,   @LockTimeout    = 60000           /* 1 minute */
    ,   @DbPrincipal    = N'public'
;

IF (@LockResult < 0) BEGIN
    THROW 50000, @LockErrorMessage, 0;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS test;

    /* EXEC MyControlledSP */
    /* For demonstration purposes only! */
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00';

    /* The work is done, release the lock */
    EXEC sys.sp_releaseapplock
            @Resource       = N'TestResource'
        ,   @LockOwner      = N'Session'
        ,   @DbPrincipal    = N'public'
    ;
END;
```

You can acquire the lock in the SP itself and run it's body only when the lock is successfully acquired, therefore any application/process using that stored procedure will implicitly also check the lock and you won't rely on having all applications/processed adjusted.

Don't forget to release the lock, especially when the owner is the session. Closing the connection (e.g. closing the query window) will automatically release the lock.

---

If the scheduled task is a SQL Server Agent job, you don't have to do a custom locking, because one job can only run once and when there is a running instance the agent will not start a second one (even if the scheduling would say so).

Comment: How will I get sp_getapplock to acquire lock for the current stored procedure? I don't want to do it for a table.

Comment: @RahulSingh Please read the documentation of the procedures. It is not locking any tables.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. I want to acquire lock for entire stored procedure. Is there something like sp_getapplock resourceName = 'my_sproc'

Comment: You can't lock a stored procedure. You can only lock a resource. But when two applications are trying to lock the same resource, one will succeed, the other will have to wait.

Comment: @RahulSingh You can set resource name (which is just arbitrary text) to your stored procedure name - makes understanding easier.

Comment: Arvo is right, you can set the name to the procedure name. Also please check the example in the answer

Comment: @Arvo If I'm understanding it correctly sys.sp_getapplock Resource = N'my_sproc' will give a lock of my Stored procedure.

Comment: @RahulSingh Not exactly - it attempts to lock resource named 'my_sproc', which just coincides with name of your procedure. Like said previously, you can use any text - applock procedures don't know anything about SQL server objects. I often use applock functionality for situations, where different procedures may alter same data - I call these eg 'sql sync active' or similar.